# Outputfield font size change

Tags: outputtext, outputfield, font

I am binding product description in outputfield but I can't able to change the font size.I am having description type as rich text area to enter bullet points description. If I use Outputtext I lam not getting the product description format correctly.So how to change the font size of outputfield as CSS style not working.See my sample below.

```
<apex:outputField  VAlue="{!line.Product2.Extended_Sales_Description__c}" style="font-size:10px;"/>
```

Also with outputText as follows

```
<apex:outputText  VAlue="{!line.Product2.Extended_Sales_Description__c}" style="font-size:10px;" escape="false"/>
```

If I remove escape="false" then font size is reduced however description forma is not retrieved correcty. How to resolve this?

Comment: Try to use the style I have mentioned ... hopefully this will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use this :

```
<apex:outputText value="{!myOppDescrp}" style="white-space: pre;font-size:15px;" escape="false"/>
```

This may solve your problem .

[image]

Comment: As I mentioned Earlier we can't use OutputText without escape ="false" as if there is no escape then description format is not correct. we need description in bullet list format

Comment: Please refer the updated code ...

Comment: this will show the out put as bullet format :

Comment: @ParthaSarathiMandal I tried the same thing earlier it's not working but after edit the product description it's working as I expect.

Answer (score 0):

The style used to display the output field component, used primarily for adding inline CSS styles. This attribute may not work for all values. If your text requires a class name, use a wrapping span tag.

Refer this https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputField.htm

Comment: styleClass not working for me